Diagram Library - how to provide additional resource information
I am using Diagrams library for diagram generation. https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/
I want the generated diagram includes additional info as well, like IP address, region, etc. for cloud resources.
How can i do it?
diagram.py
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2
from diagrams.aws.database import RDS
from diagrams.aws.network import ELB

with Diagram("Web Service", show=False):
    ELB("lb") >> EC2("web") >> RDS("userdb")

I explored the Diagram docs and searched in ChatGPT, but I couldn't find any solution.
This is what i want to show the diagrams with some additional details:

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I just updated by original query.  It's about how to display cloud resource info like IPs, region, etc. in the diagrams.
